# How do I tell write.table to save the data of each list item in a separate row?

Tags: r, list, write.table

Let's say I have this array:

```
 my.array <- array(1:48, dim=c(3,4,4))
```

And after doing some awkward transformations I end up with the following data:

```
tarray <- apply(my.array, c(1,3), t)
listarray <-apply(tarray, 3, as.list)
ulist <- lapply(listarray, unlist)
trlist <- lapply(ulist, t)

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    4    7   10    2    5    8   11    3     6
     [,11] [,12]
[1,]     9    12

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   13   16   19   22   14   17   20   23   15    18
     [,11] [,12]
[1,]    21    24

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   25   28   31   34   26   29   32   35   27    30
     [,11] [,12]
[1,]    33    36

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   37   40   43   46   38   41   44   47   39    42
     [,11] [,12]
[1,]    45    48
```

I want to save it so each list item gets its own row, i.e.

```
1 4 7 10 2 5 8 11 3 6 9 12 
13 16 19 22 14 17 20 23 15 18 21 24 
25 28 31 34 26 29 32 35 27 30 33 36
37 40 43 46 38 41 44 47 39 42 45 48
```

But when I use `write.table(trlist, file="test", sep="/t", row.names=FALSE,col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)` it just saves everything in a single row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this by looping through the third dimension, extract the 'my.array' along that dimension, transpose, concatenate to `vector` and convert it to a single matrix by `rbind`ing the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(dim(my.array)[3]), function(i) c(t(my.array[,,i]))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]    1    4    7   10    2    5    8   11    3     6     9    12
#[2,]   13   16   19   22   14   17   20   23   15    18    21    24
#[3,]   25   28   31   34   26   29   32   35   27    30    33    36
#[4,]   37   40   43   46   38   41   44   47   39    42    45    48
```

---

Or another approach would be to use `aperm` and then convert it to `matrix`

```
matrix(c(aperm(my.array, c(2, 1, 3))), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: This a great way to transform the array into what I want, but do you know how to save the data with write.table so it would save each row in a separate row instead of everything in a single row?

Comment: @Antsushi  Once you have the output i.e. `res <- do.call(rbind, ...); write.table(res, "yourdata.txt", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)`

Comment: @Antsushi  If you don't want the column names, then `write.table(res, "yourdata.txt", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)`